# Problems with the selector in a list view displaying another clickable layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a custom list view, each row has it's own custom selector, contains various misc. elements and 1 Relative layout with it's own selector. (I'm using relative layout since an Image Button won't suffice in functionality for me).

The list elements have different states, in some the whole item is clickable and the button, and in others the item shouldn't be clickable, only the relative layout(further referenced as button for simplicity).

After a lot of fiddling, I decided to solve this by setting a static background (the normal state drawable from the selector) for the non-clickable rows and the selector itself for the clickable ones. (If you have a better solution for this please feel free to correct me, it is not the point of the question but i welcome any help)

The problem is, that even though the row itself doesn't change background, the selector for the button is triggered. I tested it and the same happens when the row has the selector as it's background.

My question is why does the list item click trigger both selectors, when I am clearly clicking on the item only, when I click the button, the row selector is not triggered.

Also I should mention that in my row layout, the button is above the item selector(or is contained by it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find a proper solution for this, and I went around it a bit.

What seems to be happening is that, the onItemClick event triggers all selectors, in the custom layout, which is rather inconvinient so I skipped it, and Implemented on onClickListener on each of my views, to save the position of the element that was clicked, I set to one of my views in each element the respective position in the array as a tag. Next time i just further the click even to a custom method in the respective activity ( I mage a single adapter for 5 activities) I just check with an activity parameter which instance we are in, cast the activity variable, and call the method. If you know any better solutions please feel free to tell me.